# Problems writing a CNN classifier for on-image data

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I am writing a program to classify human activities (total 6 activities) based on 3-axis accelerometer (xyz) data from a smartphone.

I have already implemented and tested this data for other classifiers (Random forest, KNN, MLP, and LDA). All of them worked with 80-90% of accuracy.

Now, I am trying it for CNN (convolutional neural network). The problem is that I only find examples for image classification scenarios. My data is based on 3 columns (x-accel, y-accel, z-accel) and the activity column itself.

The dataframe has 2086923 rows x 4 columns.
[Find the first rows of the dataset here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oiyu7.png)

I have tried the code below, but I am pretty sure I need to reshape the dataframe. Not sure what is wrong with the `input_shape=(3,)`

```
train,test = train_test_split(df,test_size=0.3,random_state=42)
X_train = train[train.columns[2:4]]
y_train = train['Activity']
X_test = test[test.columns[2:4]]
y_test = test['Activity']

model=Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3),activation='relu',input_shape=(3,)))
model.add(MaxPool2D(2,2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(100,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(10,activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train,y_train,epochs=10)
model.evaluate(X_test,y_test)
```

I am getting the following error:

> ValueError: Input 0 of layer "conv2d_1" is incompatible with the layer: expected
> min_ndim=4, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 3)

Comment: I would suggest using 1D convolution, since I would expect the x, y, and z axes to not be interchangeable. (e.g a 1G acceleration on the Z axis could mean something different than a 1G acceleration on the X axis.) Here's an example how to use keras with 1D convolution to classify accelerometer data: https://github.com/harryjdavies/Python1D_CNNs/tree/master

Comment: Hi Matheus. The error says that the expected input of the `Conv2D` layer is `(batch, channels, height, width)`, but your data is `(batch, channels)`, hence the `(None, 3)`. The suggestion of @NickODell works fine, and I would also suggest the use of a simple MLP, starting already with a Dense layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Nick ODell and @Joao Ponte,

**Conv2D** expects [Inputshape](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv2D#input-shape) in 4D dimensions (`batch_shape + (channels, rows, cols)`) and is better used in image type of  dataset for spatial convolution over images which is causing error in your mentioned dataset.

You could use **Conv1D** which expects [Inputshape](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv1D#input-shape) in 3D dimensions (`batch_shape + (steps, input_dim)`) and expand the dimension of training data to match the Inputshape

Please check the fixed code:

```
X_train=np.expand_dims(X_train, axis=-1)
X_test=np.expand_dims(X_test, axis=-1)
X_train.shape, X_test.shape
```

Output:

```
((9, 3, 1), (5, 3, 1))
```

and the model will be:

```
model=Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(32, 3, activation='relu',input_shape=(3,1)))
model.add(MaxPool1D(pool_size=2,strides=2,padding='same'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(100,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(10,activation='softmax'))model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train,y_train,epochs=10)
model.evaluate(X_test,y_test)
```

Output:

```
Epoch 1/10
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 1s/step - loss: 1.6448 - accuracy: 0.6667
Epoch 2/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 11ms/step - loss: 1.4442 - accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 3/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 12ms/step - loss: 1.2613 - accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 4/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 12ms/step - loss: 1.0993 - accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 5/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 11ms/step - loss: 0.9577 - accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 6/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 10ms/step - loss: 0.8339 - accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 7/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 12ms/step - loss: 0.7265 - accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 8/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 13ms/step - loss: 0.6337 - accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 9/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 10ms/step - loss: 0.5537 - accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 10/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 11ms/step - loss: 0.4847 - accuracy: 1.0000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 133ms/step - loss: 0.1838 - accuracy: 1.0000
[0.18375679850578308, 1.0]
```

Comment: Hi! @TFer2 Thank you! What library did you import for MAXPOOL1D? I am using Maxpooling1D (from keras.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling1D). I have tried that, but I am getting: 19565/19565 [==============================] - 31s 2ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00

Comment: Please use `model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2,strides=2,padding='same'))` in place of `MAXPOOL1D()` layer. I am getting this as accuracy at final epoch - `Epoch 10/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 15ms/step - loss: 1.1352 - accuracy: 1.0000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 133ms/step - loss: 0.8454 - accuracy: 1.0000
[0.845375657081604, 1.0]`